# Clonar um objeto (deep copy)

Tags: java

Boa noite. Estou trabalhando em um programa que escreve um texto. Basicamente ele é composto por um objeto Texto que é uma lista de objetos Paragrafo, que é uma lista de objetos Sentencas que é uma lista de objetos Palavras que sao uma lista de Strings.

Estou tentando construir um método, que salve este texto antes de quaqluer alteracao a ser feita nele.
Obviamente comecei tentando fazer um vetor do tipo Texto que armazena o texto antes de ele ser alterado, porém, por ser um objeto, quando faco qualquer alteracao no texto por outro metodo, este que está salvo dentro do vetor também é alterado.

Dei uma pesquisada e encontrei essa tal de Deep Copy, que faz uma especie de clonagem do objeto, assim nao fazendo uma referencia a ele como o vetor faz, mas sim alocando na memoria uma copia do objeto, assim as alteracoes nao surtirao efeitos nesta copia.

Porém nao estou entendo como se faz a implementacao desta copia. Seria possivel alguem me auxiliar? Abracos.

Comment: Se você precisa salvar o estado do texto antes de ser alterado, para ter uma forma _desfazer_ a alteração, talvez o design pattern [Memento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)` te ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de se fazer isso, porém existe uma lib chamada commons-lang (muito famosa por sinal), que faz isso de uma forma muito fácil.

Clone seu objeto usando o comando:

```
SerializationUtils.clone(seuObjeto);
```

Você pode baixar a lib aqui:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Ou se utilizar maven, gradle ou afins: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

*A clonagem dos objetos só funcionará se todos os objetos que estão sendo clonados implementarem a interface Serializible.*